# PWM Ground Modulation: is this circuit going to affect my other ICs?

Tags: pwm, ground

I have designed a fan controller circuit based on the MIC 502 fan management IC:
[image: Updated Schematic]
**UPDATED SCHEMATIC**

QUESTION #1: The schematic (for the top part) is basically the one available here:
https://bit-tech.net/reviews/modding/pwm_fan_controller/1/
I understand how most of it works but I just can't tell if the PWM signal (when mixed to GND at Q2) is going to affect the main ground and the other circuits on my board? That "GND" sticker is the only GND used for the entire computer. 
-> ***Answered*** For such a small "contribution" (frequency + current consumption), it shouldn't be a problem.

QUESTION #2 (VOLTAGE COMPARATOR):
The box on the bottom "Overheating Indicator" is basically a LED controller. It checks if the temperature (or voltage) reported by the thermistor TH1 is larger than the "temperature" preset by R5/R6. If so the LED lights up. So basically, R8 is R5 and R6 is TH1@80°C. Is this new schematic correct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

NBs: "Controller+" and "Controller-" are the going straight to the fan.

Comment: shouldn't the overheating circuit be connected to pin 1 of VR1?

Comment: by the way, that "modding page" is ... not a great source for electronic circuits. Maybe just read the datasheet of the MIC502. (you might have used the OTF output directly, probably... it's exactly meant for the purpose of signalling things are too hot.)

Comment: D2 seems like its in the wrong place, is it meant to be preventing backemf?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! //// jsotola: My bad. In order to only "read" TH1, it should be placed at pin #1 of VR1, correct? Or do I need to do something else? I only want to compare the thermistor value for the "Overheating indicator" (ie when TH1 reaches 1.2k, the led should light up)
////
Marcus Müller: Perhaps I didn't read the MIC502 spec correctly, but I don't think I can "define" a specific temperature for the LED to light up? 
////
BeB00: I just copied the schematic from the link in the first post. I think that's indeed the purpose of this diode.

Answer (score 3):

*other points fixed by question update*

2. the IN2/OUT2 opamp is used as comparator (not recommended with the LM358)

That's not recommended because amplifiers that aren't meant for comparator applications can *latch-up*. Also, adding a bit of *hysteresis* sounds desirable, so that slight supply or temperature voltage variations don't lead to a flickering LED if you're close to the threshold temperature. Look for *Schmitt trigger* circuits.

---

Your schematic doesn't tell us how stable your ground is, but usually, a slow PWM like the one you're using here, switching a low current like what is necessary to drive a fan shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Re #1: I didn't know this could be a problem. I thought the LM358 could handle up to 32V. So, should I only use 12V (for both Vcc and In-/+, and adapt the resistor before the LED, see #3). Re #2: which op amp would you recommend for this application? Re #3: I added a resistor before the LED after posting here. Sorry I didn't update my post sooner. At the moment (because Vcc is 5V, I have a 120 Ohm resistor there. Also, see comment above for the reply to your other comment.

Comment: LM358 now uses 12V instead of 5. Resistor for the LED has been added.

Comment: answer updated, @LTS_student.

Comment: How about an LM393 with a Schmitt trigger circuit instead of a 358?

Comment: I have decided to use a completely different microcontroller (ATTiny85) and have written code for it to suit my application. Thank you all for your help/support. At least I learnt a few things along the way!